# Node.js and POSIX real-time signals

Tags: node.js, signals, posix

I am catching a set of the usual POSIX signals in my node.js application. Is there a way to catch the POSIX real-time signals i.e. `SIGRTMIN+n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These signals are currently not catchable with node.js/io.js. If you want to see support for this added, you should submit a [new issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/new) containing your feature request.

Comment: OK, well that answers that. It's a nuisance as the RT signals are useful for instrumentation among other things.